# KineticJS crop image after apply vertical flip

Tags: kineticjs

How can i crop a image after apply vertical flip on image? I'm using jCrop to get x, y, width and height.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't share enough information to help with code.

But clipping is done on a container, so

1. Put your image in a group,
2. Flip your image,
3. Do the clip with myGroup.clip({x:clipX,y:clipY,width:clipWidth,height:clipHeight:});

You'll have a flipped and clipped image!